# Batch : how to run a program for all files in a folder and how to create an output file for the result using the original filename?

Tags: bash, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, treetagger

I'm a noob at batch programming so excuse me for the simple question.

I have a folder called FSC in **C:\TTG\FSC**, with a thousand and thousand of text files called like **1_A.txt** **2_A.txt** etc. 
I would like to run a programm and have its output in another file renaming the original one ( for ex. 1_A.txt will have an output file called **1_A_out.txt** ). I have already tested to run the programm on 1 file and it works (simply writing on the command line *tag-french filename*).

So how can I create the for loop for parsing each file on the folder and create the output files?

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\treetagger\FSCB1\"') do
tag-french %%i > %%i_out
```

I can do it in ubuntu writing this :

```
for l in /home/sp/Desktop/FSCM5/*
do
  echo $l
  filename=$(basename "$l")
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  filename="${filename%.*}"
  filename=($(echo "/home/sp/Desktop/FSCM5TTG/"$filename"_"ttg"_."$extension))
  echo $filename
  sh /home/sp/Desktop/TTG/cmd/tree-tagger-french $l > $filename
done
```

But I would like to learn how to do this in windows too

Comment: That's what the `FOR /F` loop is for - enumerate all (matching) files in a folder, possibly recursively, and run a command on them. Type `FOR /?` to get the command syntax.

Comment: I've tried to do this but it doesn't work :

for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\treetagger\FSCB1\"') do
tag-french %%i > %%i_out

Comment: What if there are already files named `*_out.txt` in the directory?

Comment: in theory I think that " %%i_out " and in particular %%i is the name of the file so if I have three files 1_a.txt, 2_a.txt, 3_a.txt should be renamed as 1_a_out.txt 2_a_out.txt etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with success:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "c:\treetagger\FSCB1\*.*"') do tag-french "%%i" > "%%i_out"
```

I had to use the `delims=` option to preserve filenames even if they contained spaces.
**edit**: options need to be placed before the loop variable.

Comment: C:\TreeTagger>for /F %i "delims=" in ('dir /b "c:\treetagger\FSCB1\*.*"') do tag
-french "%i" > "%i_out"
"delims=" was unexpected at this time.


C:\TreeTagger>for /F %%i "delims=" in ('dir /b "c:\treetagger\FSCB1\*.*"') do ta
g-french "%%i" > "%%i_out"
%%i was unexpected at this time.

Comment: sorry, pasted a bug back in: options like "delims" need to be put before the loop variable. Code edited.

Comment: it doesn't work here : the files created are empty :\

Comment: Can we meet in chat? A one-liner shouldn't take that long to debug.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain me how?

Comment: Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/120136/for-loop-with-output-redirection?tab=general . Please post your code there.